# Scout Eclipse Outline tree width

Tags: width, outline, eclipse-scout

When I start my application the online tree take all the space available.
I know I can resize manual, but it is annoying and bad user experience.

it looks like this : [image]

I can't find where width of outline is set.

Marko

Answer (score 0):

I think it is feature:

If you change the window size of your Swing client or change the width of the outline tree view and then close my client, these values are retained: When I next start the Swing client, the window and the views have the same size as when the client was last closed.

I have explained where the preference file is located here:
[Re: Table columns order hidden cache??](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=629180&goto=1222171&#msg_1222171)

I think you should confirm that the size you see is due to this pref file.

In my opinion this feature is good for the user experience. If the user changes the dimensions of the parts in the application, next time he opens the application, its settings will be restored.

Comment: Yes :D I agree, it is good that remembers where user set his sizes. This is not my problem. My problem is after reloading server, those values is forgotten again and for all new users first time values are not good.

Comment: So my question is hot to fix that firs time user enters the application don't se image above.